# how to make the card add to the side, when I do foreach on php?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[Card looks like this. i just want it to display to the side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nChTE.png)

Im trying to show data from my database in PHP codeigniter. the data shows fine. but the problem is that the card is going down istead to right. you can look at the image above.

i just want to make the card go to the right when i do foreach. and go down after 4/5 card.

i ve tried to move the foreach code but it looks just like that.
im using bootsrap 4

here's the code

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card-body">
                <?php
                    foreach ($user as $u) {?>
                <div class="col-md-2 mt-4">
                    <div class="card mt-3" style="width:15rem;">
                        <img src="<?=base_url() . 'assets/img/' . $u->gambar_game;?>"
                            class="card-img-top img-responsive" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold  "><?php echo $u->nama_game; ?></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"><?=$u->deskripsi_game;?></p>
                        <a href="<?=base_url() . 'assets/games/' . $u->link_game;?>"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Mainkan Game</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are repeating currently the whole container inside the row, but u want to repeat the cols inside the container.

Try this (loop over the `col-md-2`):

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="card-body">
     <?php
foreach ($user as $u) {?>
                <div class="col-md-2 mt-4">
                    <div class="card mt-3" style="width:15rem;">
                        <img src="<?=base_url() . 'assets/img/' . $u->gambar_game;?>"
                            class="card-img-top img-responsive" alt="...">
                        <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold  "><?php echo $u->nama_game; ?></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"><?=$u->deskripsi_game;?></p>
                        <a href="<?=base_url() . 'assets/games/' . $u->link_game;?>"
                            class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Mainkan Game</a>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
 <?php }?>
        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
```

**EDIT:** 
Your HTML structure was a little mixed up.
Try this. `col-md-3` places 4 cols inside of your row, or `col-md-2`if you want 6 cols inside of your row. A row is max 12 cols [bootstrap grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#grid-options)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  <?php foreach ($user as $u) {?>
  <!-- col-md-2  -->
    <div class="col-md-4 mt-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
           <img src="<?=base_url() . 'assets/img/' . $u->gambar_game;?>"class="card-img-top img-responsive" alt="...">
           <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold  "><?php echo $u->nama_game; ?></h5>
           <p class="card-text"><?=$u->deskripsi_game;?></p>
           <a href="<?=base_url() . 'assets/games/' . $u->link_game;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Mainkan Game</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- col-md-2 end -->
    <?php }?>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even the `card-body` enclosing the `card` seems wrong. The `card-body` should be a child of `card` and not the other way round

Comment: its still the same dude. idk whats wrong with these. i've tried to move the foreach code so many time. but, it still doesnt  work.

Comment: i changed some things in the code. Try the new version.
Your container was inside of the row, look at the bootstrap documentation for the correct order :)

Comment: oh my god. thanks dude! you are my angelllll hahahahahahhaha thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!